# How to change select dropdown value based on click table list using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a list which contains some attribute data like `letid`,`industrysize`,`industrytypeid`. And I also have multiple select dropdowns.

What I want is that when I click on an item in the list, the dropdown will change according to the value in the list. I've made the javascript as below. But still can't. Can anyone help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.table-autocomplete td').click(function () {
    $("#select-ac").click();
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.table-autocomplete-value', function () {
    let letidValue = $(this).data('letid');
    let industrySize = $(this).data('industrysize');
    let indsutrytypeid = $(this).data('industrytypeid');

    if(letidValue === null || letidValue === ''){
      console.log(letidValue)
      console.log(industrySize)
      console.log(indsutrytypeid)
      
      $("select[name='account-industrySize']").val($(this).data('industrysize')).change();
      $("select[name='account-industrySize']").prop("disabled", false);
      $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").val($(this).data('industrytypeid')).change();
      $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").prop("disabled", false);
      $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").val($(this).data('letid')).change();
      $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").prop("disabled", false);
    }else{
      console.log(letidValue)
      console.log(industrySize)
      console.log(indsutrytypeid)

      $("select[name='account-industrySize']").val($(this).data('industrysize')).change();
      $("select[name='account-industrySize']").prop("disabled", true);
      $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").val($(this).data('industrytypeid')).change();
      $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").prop("disabled", true);
      $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").val($(this).data('letid')).change();
      $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="select-ac"></div>
<table class="table-autocomplete" id="racbe5de91fbfd94c89be790f1408638751">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-autocomplete-value" tabindex="22" data-key="22" data-industrysize="[10,100)" data-industrytypeid="13" data-letid="2">ABADI JAYA PACKING</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-autocomplete-value" tabindex="324" data-key="324" data-industrysize="[101,300)" data-industrytypeid="11" data-letid="6">ABADI JAYA PACKING</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-autocomplete-value" tabindex="23" data-key="23" data-industrysize="" data-industrytypeid="" data-letid="">ACER STORE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-autocomplete-value" tabindex="327" data-key="327" data-industrysize="[10,100)" data-industrytypeid="13" data-letid="2">ACER STORE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-autocomplete-value" tabindex="24" data-key="24" data-industrysize="[2,10)" data-industrytypeid="13" data-letid="5">ADIJAYA BUANA PERKASA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<select name="account-legalEntityType-id" id="legal-entity-type" onchange="this.style.color='black';" style="color: black;">
  <option value="" style="display:none">Jenis Perusahaan</option>
  <option value="11" style="color: black;">Lainnya</option>
  <option value="1" style="color: black;">PT</option>
  <option value="2" style="color: black;">CV</option>
  <option value="3" style="color: black;">Firma</option>
  <option value="4" style="color: black;">PD</option>
  <option value="5" style="color: black;">UD</option>
  <option value="6" style="color: black;">BUMN</option>
  <option value="7" style="color: black;">BUMD</option>
  <option value="8" style="color: black;">Lembaga</option>
  <option value="9" style="color: black;">Yayasan</option>
  <option value="10" style="color: black;">Koperasi</option>
</select>

<select name="account-industryType-id" id="company-classified" onchange="this.style.color='black';" style="color: black;">
  <option value="" style="display:none">Klasifikasi Perusahaan</option>
  <option value="11" style="color: black;">Pertambangan</option>
  <option value="12" style="color: black;">Trading</option>
  <option value="13" style="color: black;">Properti</option>
  <option value="14" style="color: black;">Pertanian</option>
  <option value="15" style="color: black;">Pertenakan</option>
  <option value="16" style="color: black;">Transportasi & Gudang</option>
  <option value="17" style="color: black;">Lainnya</option>
  <option value="1" style="color: black;">Jasa</option>
  <option value="2" style="color: black;">Kesehatan</option>
  <option value="3" style="color: black;">Kesenian & Hiburan</option>
  <option value="4" style="color: black;">Keuangan & Asuransi</option>
  <option value="5" style="color: black;">Konstruksi</option>
  <option value="6" style="color: black;">Manufaktur & Perakitan</option>
  <option value="7" style="color: black;">Pemerintahan, Badan & BUMN</option>
  <option value="8" style="color: black;">Pendidikan</option>
  <option value="9" style="color: black;">Pengelolaan Limbah</option>
  <option value="10" style="color: black;">Hotel, Restoran, Cafe</option>
</select>

<select name="account-industrySize" id="company-classified" onchange="this.style.color='black';" style="color: black;">
  <option value="" style="display:none">Jumlah Karyawan</option>
  <option value="[2,10)" style="color: black;">2-9</option>
  <option value="[10,100)" style="color: black;">10-99</option>
  <option value="[101,300)" style="color: black;">100-299</option>
  <option value="[300,)" style="color: black;">&gt;300</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the problem? AFAICT your code works here in this snippet - if I click the first  "ABADI JAYA PACKING", the 3 selects are correctly changed to the correct options.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong jQuery selector when retrieving the "data*" attributes

Your click function should look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.table-autocomplete-value', function () {
    let letidValue = $(this).data('letid');
    let industrySize = $(this).data('industrysize');
    let indsutrytypeid = $(this).data('industrytypeid');

    if(letidValue === null || letidValue === ''){
      console.log(letidValue)
      console.log(industrySize)
      console.log(indsutrytypeid)
      
      $("select[name='account-industrySize']").val($(this).data('industrysize')).change();
      $("select[name='account-industrySize']").prop("disabled", false);
      $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").val($(this).data('industrytypeid')).change();
      $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").prop("disabled", false);
      $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").val($(this).data('letid')).change();
      $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").prop("disabled", false);
    }else{
      console.log(letidValue)
      console.log(industrySize)
      console.log(indsutrytypeid)

      $("select[name='account-industrySize']").val($(this).data('industrysize')).change();
      $("select[name='account-industrySize']").prop("disabled", true);
      $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").val($(this).data('industrytypeid')).change();
      $("select[name='account-industryType-id']").prop("disabled", true);
      $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").val($(this).data('letid')).change();
      $("select[name='account-legalEntityType-id']").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  })
```

Notice I removed `$('#select-ac').data` and I put `$(this).data`